# How do I disable Visual Studio code completion popups in batch files?

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-2015, text-editor

When editing batch files in Visual Studio 2015, I get intrusive code completion popups that pop up, unbidden, and steal keystrokes. Judging by the icon, they're neither intellisense nor snippets:

[image: image of fantastically annoying popup]

How can I disable these?

(I'd assumed a .bat file would be plain text (the properties window for it doesn't say one way or the other) - but perhaps not, as there's some sensible syntax colouring. But either way, there are no batch file specific options in the options dialog, and no code completion popup options for  plain text.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colorization and code completion come from the same secret place:
"TextMate Grammars".

It's a bit of an amputation but I was able to disable the code completion by
renaming the language definition file. Look in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\00u3r3fs.dwy\Starterkit\Extensions\bat\syntaxes` to find `Batch File.tmLanguage` - I changed the extension to tmLanguageNot and VS2015 seems to have given up on popups (yay) and colorizing (oh well) for .bat files.

If the `00u3r3fs.dwy` part isn't on your system (install-specific perhaps?) just search for *.tmLanguage.

Comment: Looks like the folder names are indeed install-specific... and I've got 3 copies of the tmLanguage file, for some reason! Very odd.